# Random sampling from gridded data: How to implement this in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, datagrid, distribution, sampling, random

I have a `200x200` gridded data points. I want to randomly pick `15` grid points from that grid and replace the values in those grids with values selected from a known distribution shown below. All `15` grid points are assigned random values from the given distribution.

The given distribution is:

```
Given Distribution
314.52
1232.8
559.93
1541.4
264.2
1170.5
500.97
551.83
842.16
357.3
751.34
583.64
782.54
537.28
210.58
805.27
402.29
872.77
507.83
1595.1
```

The given distribution is made up from `20` values, which are part of those gridded data points. These `20` grid points are fixed i.e. they must not be part of randomly picking `15` points. The coordinates of these `20` points, which are fixed and should not be part of random picking, are:

```
x   27  180 154 183 124 146 16  184 138 122 192 39  194 129 115 33  47  65  1   93
y   182 81  52  24  168 11  90  153 133 79  183 25  63  107 161 14  65  2   124 79
```

Can someone help with how to implement this problem in Matlab?

Comment: Your question is not well formulated and there are two votes to close as _not a real question_. The way it reads now, it also looks like homework, and if it's so, mark it so. You might want to look into the `randi` function to generate a random list of integers less than a certain value to pick your points. Also, a [CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) has a max value of 1. What do those values in your table represent? At first I assumed they were histogram bin counts, but it can't be those either. If you meant a different CDF, then you should explain that too.

Comment: Which part of the question you do not understand? I did not say the given table *is* CDF. I said the CDF *comes* from the given values. I have explained the question very clearly and I don't understand what is not clearly explained, as you say. This is not a Homework, rather its part of my research.

Comment: By the way those who voted to close this question dont think that they have a legitimate demand to mark this question as *not a real question*. If their concern were legitimate and real then they would have asked or questioned about it.

Comment: I've already pointed you towards 1 & 2. I have also explained which part of your question is unclear. It might serve you well to bring down your tone a notch and read the comment first. "Say that CDF comes from these values" makes no sense. How do you get the CDF from those values? Are those the raw "frequency" values? Should you normalize by the area? Or are they the actual CDF evaluated at those points, but just scaled in which case, you just need to scale it back? Nothing is clear. If you need help, you'll have to explain it so that it is clear to _us_ and not to _yourself_.

Comment: Alright Yoda. I have reformatted the question so that it is more understandable now. Thanks for pointing out the doubts.

Comment: Ok, just to clarify: if say a point `(x1,y1)=(70,140)` is picked at random, how do you go about assigning a value from the distribution? Do you just pick another random value from the distribution or do you have to interpolate the distribution to `(x1,y1)` and assign that value?

Comment: @yoda: Just pick another random value from the distribution. See the updated question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of [my answer to your simpler question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874105/how-to-compare-the-pairs-of-coordinates-most-efficiently-without-using-nested-loo/5874517#5874517), here is a solution for how you can choose 15 random integer points (i.e. subscripted indices into your 200-by-200 matrix) and assign random values drawn from your set of values given above:

```
mat = [...];   %# Your 200-by-200 matrix
x = [...];     %# Your 20 x coordinates given above
y = [...];     %# Your 20 y coordinates given above
data = [...];  %# Your 20 data values given above
fixedPoints = [x(:) y(:)];         %# Your 20 points in one 20-by-2 matrix
randomPoints = randi(200,[15 2]);  %# A 15-by-2 matrix of random integers
isRepeated = ismember(randomPoints,fixedPoints,'rows');  %# Find repeated sets of
                                                         %#   coordinates
while any(isRepeated)
  randomPoints(isRepeated,:) = randi(200,[sum(isRepeated) 2]);  %# Create new
                                                                %#   coordinates
  isRepeated(isRepeated) = ismember(randomPoints(isRepeated,:),...
                                    fixedPoints,'rows');  %# Check the new
                                                          %#   coordinates
end
newValueIndex = randi(20,[1 15]);  %# Select 15 random indices into data
linearIndex = sub2ind([200 200],randomPoints(:,1),...
                      randomPoints(:,2));  %# Get a linear index into mat
mat(linearIndex) = data(newValueIndex);    %# Update the 15 points
```

In the above code I'm assuming that the `x` coordinates correspond to row indices and the `y` coordinates correspond to column indices into `mat`. If it's actually the other way around, swap the second and third inputs to the function [SUB2IND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think yoda already gave the basic idea.  Call randi twice to get the grid coordinate to replace, and then replace it with the appropriate value.  Do that 15 times.